# About routing between multiple locations with truck

Tags: here-api

I have the following content in the link (https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/routing.html):

You can use RouteWaypoint to add more waypoint details to your route calculations. These details include whether the waypoint is a deliberate stopover or a crossing point through which the route must pass. This affects routing because the path containing the stopover or route may be different. For example, the calculated route may suggest a U-turn maneuver after a stopover, while a route containing the same location as the waypoint is recommended to continue on the same street. The via waypoint type is only supported in car routes and is not supported in other route types.

I guess this passage means that your company's SDK supports path planning between multiple points, but it seems to only support the "car" type. I want to confirm if the truck type is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple waypoints for Trucks is supported, but waypoints will always be of type "Stop_Over" , you cannot have a waypoint as type "Via_point" when using Truck Routing. More details can be found in https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteWaypoint.Type.html

**VIA_WAYPOINT**

public static final RouteWaypoint.Type VIA_WAYPOINT

No maneuver is generated for a VIA waypoint. After the VIA waypoint, route will continue in the same direction as when it's approached.

Via waypoints will "force" the route to pass through them, but they will not cause any guidance, announcement or maneuvers.

VIA waypoints are not considered during Guidance triggered re-routing nor do they trigger any callbacks upon arrival at the waypoint.

This is only supported by **RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR** . It's ignored for other transport modes.